# Last-child selector

Tags: css

I'm a bit confused about the use of the :last-child selector. I have different buttons with the mark-up like this:

```
<div class="people">
    <a href="pd.html" title="Post-Doctorate's">
        <div class="people-button">Post-Doctorate's</div>
    </a>
    <a href="staff.html" title="Staff">
        <div class="people-button">Staff</div>
    </a>
    <a href="phdstudents.html" title="PhD Students">
        <div class="people-button">PhD Students</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now I want to give the last button a different margin-bottom so I tried to use this:

```
.people a:last-child .people-button {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

But it seems this is not the correct selector. Any help or explanation on how to do this?

Comment: Your code works perfect : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/43q4M/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/g5enJ/

Comment: do you mean `padding-bottom` instead? http://jsfiddle.net/e4TS2/1/ It works as intended.

Comment: That code works fine. Which browser are you using? http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child

Comment: Yes, I think what you are looking for is padding.

Comment: You've used corectly the pseudo-selector. If it's not what you wanted, check the context, maybe it is overwritten by a more specific rule

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right and works ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7CNv/)), but only in supported browsers.
ie: `last-child` won't work below IE9.

To see compatibility table see:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child)

Another, issue is that it could be overridden by another CSS rule with major precedence. Use Developer Tool (F12) in your browser OR context menu (right-click the anchor) for inspect the element.

Generally, the browser will show in the right pane for this element, the computed CSS styles & all styles that were applied (and overriden).

---

You could rewrite your code. Take off the `div`s inside `a`, and set `a` as `display: block` to break line and work padding:

```
<a href="pd.html" title="Post-Doctorate's" class="people-button">
    Post-Doctorate's
</a>
<a href="staff.html" title="Staff" class="people-button">
    Staff
</a>
<a href="phdstudents.html" title="PhD Students" class="people-button">
    PhD Students
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.people-button {
    display: block;
}
.people a:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 50px;     /* if you want space inside anchor */
    background-color: #0aa;
}
.people {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom: 20px;     /* if you just want space at bottom of container */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m7CNv/2/

Comment: awesome.. I propose an answer, the only vote is a downvote without any explanation

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out where the problem of the overridden code was exactly situated so I tried your suggestion and it worked, thank you!

Comment: Just figured out something else by the way: the possibility of just using the :last-of-type selector and then writing

.people-button:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}